# Powershell Append () attribute on xml defined position

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to add an attribute on root element, but in certain position:

```
<METATRANSCRIPT xmlns="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
     Date="2016-01-29" FormatId="IMDI 3.03" Originator="" Type="SESSION" 
     Version="0" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mpi.nl/IMDI/Schema/IMDI ./IMDI_3.0.xsd" 
     ArchiveHandle="">
```

The attribute `ArchiveHandle=""` needs to stay between `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and `Date="2016-01-29"`.

How can I solve this, and put the attribute in the right place?

This is my code:

```
   Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\XML\Files' -Recurse -Include "*.imdi" -File | ForEach-Object
  {

  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName; 
  $xml= $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.OuterXml;
  $xmlAtt = $xml.CreateAttribute("ArchiveHandle")
  $xsi= $xml.DocumentElement.xsi
  $xmlAttRef = $xml.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append($xmlAtt)
  $xml.Save($_.FullName)
  }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `Attributes.Append` method will always append new attributes at the end.  Thus, what you really want to use is either `Attributes.InsertBefore` method or `Attributes.InsertAfter` method.

For example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Path\To\XML\Files' -Recurse -Include '*.imdi' -File | ForEach-Object {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
    if ($xml.METATRANSCRIPT.HasAttribute('ArchiveHandle'))
    {
        $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.RemoveAttribute('ArchiveHandle')
    }

    $ah = $xml.CreateAttribute('ArchiveHandle')
    $dt = $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Attributes.GetNamedItem('Date')
    $ah = $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Attributes.InsertBefore($ah, $dt)
    $xml.Save($_.FullName)
}
```

In my snippet above, I am explicitly removing any pre-existing `ArchiveHandle` attribute.  Then, after creating a new `ArchiveHandle` attribute, I get the `XmlAttribute` of the item I want to insert my new attribute before (eg, `Date`), then call the `Attributes.InsertBefore` method accordingly.  I could have easily chosen `xmlns:xsi` then called the `Attributes.InsertAfter` method.  Finally, I save the resulting XML (for each file found by `Get-ChildItem`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi LeeHarvey1, thanks a lot for your help and explanation. It works fine, and solves my issue.